# Are there any examples of Humans and Aliens producing offspring in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

The title is pretty self explanatory, although to expand on the question further I am looking for any examples of inter-species **breeding** in the Star Wars universe, not just inter-species (ahem) "*relations*".

Comment: Open-ended lists are not a good fit for this site, nor are questions that can be very easily googled.

Comment: @Richard - this question isn't easily googled unless you know the term Hybrid (and "not a good fit for the site is inaccurate, as General Reference was burninated as close reason by community consensus, with good reasons). And it isn't "open ended list" - Disney canon has at most 1 or 2 examples.

Comment: Is this actually limited to Star Wars? I see the tag but no evidence in the question body or title. Without constraining this to Star Wars I would say this is rather open-ended.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - yes, I've edited to make it a little clearer.

Comment: @dvk - If you google the title, the first page contains all three links in your answer.

Comment: @GorchestopherH The question is tagged "star-wars"

Comment: @Richard I did google the question and the only semi-relevant result was http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Inter-Species_Reproduction and it doesn't cover Star Wars....

Comment: @DustinJackson - Your results may be dissimilar from mine, but merely googling the question (as originally written) shows *multiple* relevant links on the first page.

Comment: See: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hybrid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a supposed (not certain if adopted or birth) human/alien offspring in New Disney canon - Clone Wars episode "*[The Deserter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Deserter)*" has [2 Human/Twi'lek hybrid kids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jek_Lawquane).

There are lots more examples in Legends (EU C-canon). [Wookieepedia "Hybrid" page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hybrid) lists several examples, e.g. Human-[Coynite](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coynite).

Comment: Was inter-breeding with a Togruta possible?

Comment: @DustinJackson - "Not from a *Jedi*"

Comment: I read on  [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cut_Lawquane web page)page which explains that Cut was not his kid's biological father, but rather their adoptive father. I had to type the URL in though because Google is not showing any results on the wiki page.

Comment: The 2 children were a mixed breed of human and twi'lek. But they were not the troopers kids, correct.

Comment: I'll watch the episode later and edit with my findings

Comment: What Disney canon source says the kids in "The Deserter" are hybrids?  I don't see any evidence that any human-alien hybrids are Disney canon.